# Flutter app stuck on spalsh screen ios, but app works in Android devices

Tags: ios, flutter, dart

I got a very annoying bug, my app works perfectly on Android devices, but In ios it gets stuck on the splash screen. I don't know how to fix this, in any possible ways that cause the problem?
////
I'm testing my ios app in VMware MacOs Catalina, Simulator

**How do you think bug comes from code or from system? Or how I can identify what cause the problem, any possible ways?**

```
u flutter doctor -v
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 2.0.4, on Mac OS X 10.15.3 19D76 darwin-x64, locale
    ru-KZ)
    • Flutter version 2.0.4 at /Users/shukur/Downloads/flutter
    • Framework revision b1395592de (9 days ago), 2021-04-01 14:25:01 -0700
    • Engine revision 2dce47073a
    • Dart version 2.12.2

[✗] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices
    ✗ Unable to locate Android SDK.
      Install Android Studio from:
      https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      On first launch it will assist you in installing the Android SDK
      components.
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup
      for detailed instructions).
      If the Android SDK has been installed to a custom location, please use
      `flutter config --android-sdk` to update to that location.


[!] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS
    • Xcode at /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer
    • Xcode 11.3.1, Build version 11C505
    ! Xcode 11.3.1 out of date (12.0.1 is recommended).
      Download the latest version or update via the Mac App Store.
    • CocoaPods version 1.10.1

[✗] Chrome - develop for the web (Cannot find Chrome executable at
    /Applications/Google Chrome.app/Contents/MacOS/Google Chrome)
    ! Cannot find Chrome. Try setting CHROME_EXECUTABLE to a Chrome executable.

[!] Android Studio (not installed)
    • Android Studio not found; download from
      https://developer.android.com/studio/index.html
      (or visit https://flutter.dev/docs/get-started/install/macos#android-setup
      for detailed instructions).

[✓] Connected device (1 available)
    • iPhone 11 Pro Max (mobile) • 051A9E22-C99F-4531-B1AA-917BA8F0E332 • ios •
      com.apple.CoreSimulator.SimRuntime.iOS-13-3 (simulator)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this error just by testing the app on a real iPhone device!
Cheers!